# Combining non LVM and LVM partitions

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I need to extend my /dev/sda7 partition to also include /dev/sda6 which is an LVM2 partition. Note that the data on /dev/sda7 must be maintained while those on /dev/sda6 may be deleted or formated. Is there a way to do this? Help is appreciated. I have also provided the output of fdisk below:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf4c7a440

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    718847    716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848 204802047 204083200  97.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       204802048 426895244 222093197 105.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       426895358 976773119 549877762 262.2G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       590852096 591876095   1024000   500M 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       591878144 976773119 384894976 183.5G 8e Linux LVM
/dev/sda7       426895360 583352319 156456960  74.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda8       583354368 590837759   7483392   3.6G 82 Linux swap /Solaris

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```